# STL algorithms and nested for loops

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm currently trying to learn more about STL algorithms and tried searching online if it was possible to create a nested for loop with STL algorithms, but just haven't gotten the answer I was looking for. Essentially, Inside OrderManager, I have a vector of class CustomerOrders that contains an array of orders. Inside ItemManager, It has a vector of class Items that are currently available. What I'm trying to achieve in the code below is to output any items that the customer requests as "unavailable". As you can see, I've created a nested for loop, but ultimately, I'd like to achieve this through STL algorithms if it is possible.

If anything is a bit too confusing or if I've somehow formatted this post incorrectly, please let me know.

```
void OrderManager::validate(const ItemManager& itemManager, std::ostream&  os)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < std::vector<CustomerOrder>::size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < std::vector<CustomerOrder>::at(i).noOrders(); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < itemManager.size(); i++)
            {
                    if (std::vector<CustomerOrder>::at(i)[j] == itemManager.at(k).getName())
                    {
                       break;
                    }
                    if (k == itemManager.size() - 1)
                    { 
                       os << std::vector<CustomerOrder>::at(i)[j] << " is unavailable." << std::endl; 
                    }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: `i < std::vector<CustomerOrder>::size()`? Is this even *real* code?

Comment: As written the code doesn't make any sense and shouldn't compile! `std::vector<CustomerOrder>` is a type name and `size()` is *not* a `static` function on that type. That said, you can just decompose your task into function objects, each implemented in terms of one or more STL algorithms.

Comment: BTW, you seem to need `std::find_if`

Comment: Sorry, I've editted the post twice to clarify it somewhat better. OrderManager inherits a vector of CustomerOrders. class OrderManager : public std::vector<CustomerOrder> {

Comment: The code does not compile. End of story. Cannot help you with code that does not compile

Comment: @Nawaz I was looking through the c++ documentary and noticed the std::find_if function and for_each function, but don't know to implement it properly

Comment: @Ed Heal it's compiling fine on my end, unless i'm breaking some type of rule?

Comment: Really - See @DietmarKühl comment. How does `std::vector<CustomerOrder>::at` work without the knowledge of an object

Comment: 3 nested loops; ouch. This looks expensive. I hope whatever you loop over is *small*.

Comment: @Ed Heal I have a orderManager class that inherits a vector of CustomerOrders and in my main function I create an instance of OrderManager. I then read the file of customerOrders and create an instance of CustomerOrders of each record, which then gets .push_back() into OrderManager.

Comment: @TheNubProgrammer - Ok. So do you think that a vector of CustomerOrder isa OrderManager? Seems rather an odd relationship and ignores encapsulation

Comment: @EdHeal Yes it is an odd relationship and ignores encapsulation, but I wanted to know if it were possible to use STL algorithms for my scenario.

Comment: So, this code is certainly not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org): it certainly isn't self-contained and complete. Still, the required logic can be decomposed into STL algorithms inside some function objects. For example, your inner loop is a `std::find_if()` if followed by a check whether a result was found.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks. It seems I'd have to use for_each for each loop and std::find_if() to do the check as you've said.

Comment: It seems that you want to find items that appear in order but not in item manager. I guess you can also take a look at std::set_difference

Answer (score 0):

it could be done with std::for_each and lambdas but that seems a bit silly for this operation,

```
std::for_each(orders.cbegin(), orders.cend(), [&ostrm] (CustomerOrder const & order) {
  std::vector<Item> const & noOrders = order.NoOrders();
  std::for_each(noOrders.cbegin(), noOrders.cend(), [&ostrm] (Item const & item) { ostrm << item; });
});
```

Comment: I see! This is an interesting approach. I'm going to test it out.